# How can I test a full Qt5 GUI using qtestlib?

Tags: c++, user-interface, testing, qt5, qtestlib

Using `qtestlib` with my **Qt5** C++ widgets application, how can I test my *full GUI*?

In the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial3-example.html) for `qtestlib`, it is explained how I could test an indivdual `QWidget` by simulating keypresses etc, however this seems impossible to do for a full UI, because the individual widgets of my UI are  hidden inside the *automatically generated* `ui_XXX.h` file.

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your ui files you can give names to the widgets. You can then search through the children from your toplevel widget.

For example to test that a Label reflects the characters entered into a LineEdit you could use:

```
MainWindow win;

QLineEdit *edit = win.findChild<QLineEdit *>("myLineEdit");
QTest::sendKeys(edit, "Example");

QLabel *label = win.findChild<QLabel *>("myLabel");
QCOMPARE(label->text(), "Example");
```